# Does a Key-Value type table still needs a auto increment key?

Tags: database-design, schema

Suppose that I have a very simple table to store variable-like data, like this:

`+-----------+-----------------+
|    key    |      value      |
+-----------+-----------------+
| site_url  | helloworld.com  |
| site_name | Hello World     |
| time_zone | Asia Taipei     |
+-----------+-----------------+`

Do I still need to create a `ID` column?
or just simply set `key` column as primary key
(`key` would be unique

Comment: If `key` is unique, then I don't see any reason to add another artificial unique key. But then it also depends on the DBMS you are using (e.g. when using a clustered index for the primary key).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always start by identifying your natural keys, in this case `key`. If these are too complex (too many columns) or not stable enough (changes to often), consider adding a surrogate key (such as the `ID` column you mention). The criteria I use for keys are:

```
- unique
- stable
- irreducible
- complexity
- familiarity
```

In many situations there will be a conflict between these criteria, and one have to compromise. There is nothing wrong with adding a surrogate key under certain circumstances, but sadly many people design by auto-pilot and blindly add surrogate keys no matter what.

Comment: +1 for "*but sadly many people design by auto-pilot and blindly add surrogate keys no matter what*"

Comment: Excellent, for the "auto-pilot" bit.  Design principles are no substitute for thought.